# run findbugs through maven eclipse

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin

how to run findbugs through eclipse with maven project. I have configured in maven as:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.home.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>home-app</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>home-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>       
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <effort>Max</effort>
          <threshold>Low</threshold>
          <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase> 
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal> 
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>         
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

i want to know what are the errors/warnings reported by findbugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the report during the usual compile package phase created in the target directory. If you like to see a more readable output you have to use the findbugs goal in the reporting block instead of the build block.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use the findbugs eclipse plugin which will give you a nice eclipse window that points you directly to all of your bugs.